# Package install fails due to not finding XOpenDisplay

Tags: configuration

I am trying to install a package which requires me to run `.configure`.

When I run the `.configure` command, it errors out by not finding `XOpenDisplay`:

```
Checking for XOpenDisplay... not found
Node libs/gui/xopendisplay/cflags is required but provided detection callback fails to find that feature on that system.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I can't find `XOpenDisplay` as a package to install.

Does anyone know what it is or what I can do?

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; where packages are built for releases and we don't know yours. XOpenDisplay (https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man3/XOpenDisplay.3.html) is a function of X Server, but we don't know if you're using X.Org, Wayland, or just using a Server with terminals.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what software you are trying to build, but check its list of prerequisites and make sure that you have installed them - based on the error message, it looks like you need to install at least the `libx11-dev` package

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So the OS is 22.04. When I type "xdpyinfo | grep version" I get: X.Org version: 1.22.1.1. So I guess this confirms I am using Xorg. The package I want to install is called xschem: https://xschem.sourceforge.io/stefan/index.html. Below is the list of prerequisites: - X11
- tcl-tk libs and developent files
- c99 compiler
- bison (only for compiling the grammar parser)
- flex (only for compiling the lexical analyzer
- Xpm library and -dev header files
- awk (tested with gawk and mawk)

Comment: So in the list of prerequisites it says X11. I have X.Org v 1.22.1.1 on my system. Do I need to install the libx11-dev package then?

Comment: Just adding, I am not very experience with installing packages in Linux (if that wasnt already obvious:-)!) so thanks very much for the help. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Yes, to build X11 software from source you will also need the `libx11-dev` package. For this particular software you will also need `libxpm-dev` and `libtk-dev`. The latter will install `libtcl-dev` as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks a million for all the help! Working now:-)! In the end I had to ensure all the following was installed:   libX11-6              libx11-dev
  libxrender1           libxrender-dev
  libxcb1               libx11-xcb-dev        
  libcairo2             libcairo2-dev
  tcl8.6                tcl8.6-dev
  tk8.6                 tk8.6-dev
  flex                  bison
  libxpm4               libxpm-dev

Comment: First tool Ive had to install where I couldnt completely rely on apt-get getting me the latest version and all the pre-requisits. A good learning experience! Thanks again for the help.